# 'Name or service not known' sending email

Tags: python, email

I want to send emails to email list that I have in an excel sheet file.

I'm using Visual Studio Code and the Linux operating system.

Please check my code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

SenderAddress = "my@emailaddress"
password = "mypassword"

e = pd.read_excel("email.xlsx")
emails = e['Emails'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com ", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(SenderAddress, password)
msg = "Hello this is a email form python"
subject = "Hello world"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, msg)
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
server.quit()
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
line 9, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com ", 587)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 308, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.683 seconds
```

Comment: Can you `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from the same machine?

Comment: You need to have ```ehlo```. Like ```server.ehlo()```

Answer (score 2):

We need to have `ehlo` as shown below:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space at the end of the hostname

```
"smtp.gmail.com "
```

Remove the space.